# Where do these coordinates bring me on my Treasure Trail?

Tags: runescape

I got a hard clue scroll at it says for me to go to [image]

I have the map, compass, and the sextant.

How do I use this to get to the next scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find a coordinate clue, you need to have the map, compass, and sextant in your inventory, and you need a spade to dig at the destination. Both the map and the compass can be added to the toolbelt, so you don't need to remember to carry them around.

When you use the sextant, you will see an image similar to the one below, and some arrows. Click the arrows until the horizon is in the center of the viewport and the center of the sun is on the horizon. Then you can click "Get Location" and you will get your current North-South and East-West coordinates. All of this information comes from [tip.it](http://www.tip.it/runescape/pages/view/treasure_trails_coords.htm).

[image: Sextant sun and horizon image]

Alternatively, you can look up your coordinate in a list such as [this one](http://www.tip.it/runescape/pages/view/treasure_trails_coords.htm#list). In your particular case, that list gives the description

> Kharazi Jungle, on the small peninsula in the most South-western corner. Dig 2 steps North of the corpse. You must have started the Legends Quest and bring a machete and hatchet to get into the Kharazi Jungle. Saradomin wizard will attack.

and the corresponding image

[image: Clue scroll destination image]

Comment: I dropped the scroll due to the fact that i need to do the Legends Guild to get back there.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot if not all of the Treasure Trails on some of the RuneScape fansites. When doing Treasure Trails I haven't been lead astray by using runehq. I got this from [runehq.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTKrI.png).

08 degrees 26 minutes south
10 degrees 28 minutes east

> In the Kharazi Jungle, dig near a corpse on the small peninsula in the southwestern corner. The Legends' Quest is required to do this. For level 3 clues: A Saradomin wizard will appear. Kill him and then dig again to get a casket
>   clue scroll.
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of online guides for Runescape clue scrolls. Assuming this isn't going to be your last one, I suggest looking up some guides which have basically all the answers to clue scrolls.

Here is where I tend to look for clue scroll clues:
[Clue Scroll Guide - Zybes](http://www.zybez.net/guides/57/clue_scrolls/)

Just remember the essentials which can also be found on the site. Good Luck!